# Making PopupMenu work

Tags: android, view, popupmenu

I having trouble on how to implement this Popup Menu. Im using ListActivity, and i dont know how to make this Popup Menu work. Can you please help me with this?

```
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_albums, null);

        imgClick = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_click_imageView1);
        imgClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(AlbumsActivity.this,imgClick);
                pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,pop.getMenu());

                pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
                        Toast.makeText(AlbumsActivity.this,"text"+item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(AlbumsActivity.this,NexActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                pop.show();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: "R.menu.menu"  does it contain item value ...??

Comment: yes it contains a value

Comment: What do i need to make this work? programs running with no error but this part is not clickable or not working.

Comment: First you have to check your ImageView clicklistener its get a listener or not ?? and in menu make sure value should be in <item> tag

Comment: @QuokMoon my image is set to clickable. and yes the menu is set also. How to call the public View getView()?

Comment: getView() mthod override from extend Fragment so you need pass intent always use getActivity()    look at this.... Intent intent = new Intent( getActivity(),NexActivity.class);

Comment: Im not using a Fragment. Im extending ListActivity. Im really confused with the two.